# How does distrubuted caching mechanism work?

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I am wondering how hazelcast or ehcache  variants  achieve cross jvm caching while every jvm instance has its own memory area.How does map objects shared in grid memory model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the cache implementation.

If we look at a regular map in Hazelcast, then the data is partitioned. By default in 271 partitions. So imagine you have 271.000 key/values, then each partition will get 1000 of key/values.

Each partition is assigned to a machine. So if we need to do e.g. map.get("foo"), which is perhaps mapped to partition 25 (we determine the hash of the key and based on that we look in the partition table which member owns partition 25). Then we send a request to that machine which returns the value for key "foo".

So that is roughly how a regular partitioned map (IMap) in Hazelcast works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,so where the partition table is stored ,in which machine or jvm? For example how any hazelcast instance knows where it needs to check or request for partitioning table.For example lets say we're running three hazelcast instances working on different jvms but same machine.how do you provide some memory area  accessible for these 3 jvm instances.

Comment: Each machine will always have an up to data copy. When a member joins/leaves, all members will get a new copy.